# My healthbar function is defined but when trying to add it to a string it is "Not defined"

Tags: python

I'm making a small adventure game and in advance I decided to try and figure out the def function because I have no clue how it works. This was my attempt after referencing some material and everything looks correct but when trying to string it in it is apparently not defined.

```
#Health test


print('Would you like to check your health?')
healthCheck = input()

if healthCheck == 'Y':
    print('Your current health is ' + str(healthBar) + '!')
    



def int(healthBar):
    healthBar == 100
    if healthBar == 0:
        print('You have died')
```

My initial plan was to do this:

```
print('Would you like to check your health?')
healthCheck = 100
answer = input()

if healthCheck == 0:
    print('You have died!')

if answer == 'Y':
    print('Your current health is ' + str(healthCheck) + '!')
```

But I figured def was a more efficient method.

Comment: `healthBar` is a local variable inside the `int()` function.  It is not visible outside of that function.

Comment: Also, why on earth did you name that function `int()`?  It seems like you were trying to declare the `healthBar` variable as an integer, but ... that's completely the wrong way to do that.

Comment: I thought if I made it an int I would be able to use it in expressions, like any other integer.

Comment: I'm very new to python @JohnGordon

Comment: If you want to make it an int, then do that.  `healthBar = 100`.  No need for a function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are just "jump" instructions and are used to organize code into nice callable blocks. In your case, it seems like you want to organize the logic of checking whether a player has died into its own block. You can do something like this:

```
def check_health(healthBar, answer):
    if healthBar == 0:
        print('You have died!')

    if answer == 'Y':
        print('Your current health is ' + str(healthBar) + '!')

print('Would you like to check your health?')
answer = input()

healthCheck = 100
check_health(healthCheck, answer)
```

There are a couple issues with your code:

1. You are using int as the function name. int is a keyword in Python so you should use a custom name.
2. You never actually call the function after defining it. Notice how I define it with `def` (def means define) at the top. Then, I call it later on by doing `check_health(healthCheck, answer)`
3. You are referencing a variable that is defined in the function. When you define healthBar inside the function, you cannot access it from outside the function. You can return values from your function in order to access them outside the function.

More information and examples of functions: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function

Comment: Hey, greatly appreciate the feedback and you referencing some material where I can read up on the topic. Thank you!

Comment: How would I go about turning the value of "healthbar" into an integer so I can subtract from it?

Comment: @Virtx_x well, with this function-based implementation, you would store the 'healthBar' variable somewhere, and pass the 'healthBar' variable into the 'check_health' function. Alternatively, you could use a class-based implementation ([encapsulating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) the current health value with the code which uses said health value), which may end up being a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a function before you reference it, and you're defining your function incorrectly.

Currently, you have defined a function called `int` (accepting a parameter called `healthBar` which is immediately overwritten in the function). Furthermore, functions are fundamentally used as a means of telling the program to do a certain thing (without you needing to write out that code every single time), but doesn't encapsulate data.

However, for your use case, you might be better off defining a `Health` class instead, as that will allow you to store a `hp` value (within that class) and use the functionality for that health value within that class.

Something along these lines:

```python
class Health():
    """class that holds functionality for health stuff"""
    
    def __init__(self, startHealth: int = 100):
        """
        creates this object, giving it startHealth health
        (100 health if startHealth not given)
        :param startHealth: how much HP to start with
        """
        self._hp: int = startHealth
        """ current HP """
        self._maxHP: int = startHealth
        """ maximum HP """
        
    def checkHealth(self) -> str:
        """
        this function checks current HP and
        returns string telling us what state
        this object is in
        """
        
        if (self._hp <= 0):
            return "You are dead!"
        else:
            return f"You have {self._hp} health!"
            
    def getHealth(self) -> int:
        """obtains current health
        :returns: current HP """
        return self._hp
        
        
    def adjustHealth(self, changeAmount: int, printHP: bool = True):
        """
        :param changeAmount: this will get added to current HP
        :param printHP: if true, we print our new HP
        """
        self.setHealth(self._hp + changeAmount, printHP)
        
    def setHealth(self, newHP: int, printHP: bool = True):
        """
        :param newHP: new current HP value
        :param printHP: if true, we print our new HP
        """
        self._hp = newHP
        if (self._hp < 0):
            self._hp = 0
        elif (self._hp > self._maxHP):
            self._hp = self._maxHP
        
        if (printHP):
            print(self.checkHealth())
```

and if you want to see it in action, here's some code that will demonstrate its functionality:

```python
helf: Health = Health(100)

print(f"initial health check: {helf.checkHealth()}")
print("> oh no a giant enemy crab just dealt 10 damage to you!")
helf.adjustHealth(-10)
print("> wow you found ye healing potion! regain 5 hp!")
helf.adjustHealth(5);
print("> giant enemy crab used 2018 humour on you! It's super effective! It just dealt 999 damage to you!")
helf.adjustHealth(-999);
print("> your corpse used life insurance! Revive with 50 HP!")
helf.setHealth(50);
print("> etc")
```

output:

```txt
initial health check: You have 100 health!
> oh no a giant enemy crab just dealt 10 damage to you!
You have 90 health!
> wow you found ye healing potion! regain 5 hp!
You have 95 health!
> giant enemy crab used 2018 humour on you! It's super effective! It just dealt 999 damage to you!
You are dead!
> your corpse used life insurance! Revive with 50 HP!
You have 50 health!
etc
```